# Can't get input value in Angular (Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-model

I'm new to Angular and Ionic and I have problem with getting value of input. I get "undefined". Here is my code:

```js
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.submit = function () {
    console.log($scope.name);
  }
  
}
```

```html
 <form ng-submit="submit()">
   <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  
   <button class="button">Send</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: What is error text?

Comment: you are missing ); after your controller declaration

Comment: Sure, but I just lose it while pasting code ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <form>
   <input type="text" ng-model="name">

   <button ng-click="submit()" class="button">Send</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(
submit() is running but still I get "undefined" text

Comment: It works in your code but not in mine. I have identical code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
   <input type="text" ng-model="FinalData.name" name="name">
    <button class="button">Send</button>
 </form>
```

And then in controller

```
   $scope.FinalData={};

   $scope.FinalData.name ="dasda";

   $scope.submit = function(){

   console.log($scope.FinalData.name);

   }
```

Comment: It works when I do $scope.name="asdasd" but I need to get it from input value.

Comment: Then dont assign value to FinalData.name..pass empty string.

Comment: It's not empty... Nevemind, I have don't this width pure javascript and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this example

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Hello World!';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='myCtrl'>

<form ng-submit="submit()">
   <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  
   <button class="button">Send</button>
 </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```